# ngRepeat won't orderBy properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Angular 1.2.10 (~ Stable ~)

I have something like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="server in servers.hits.hits | orderBy: type.id">
```

My server object look like this :

```
server = {
    name = "String",
    type = {
            id: Integer,
            label: "String"
           },
    url: "String"
}
```

My server list is not organized properly but in an Angular-UI < select > it works.
Plus I don't know if it's possible but I sometimes need to put a double orderBy
( | orderBy:['id', 'label'] ) but also it won't work.

Anyone knows what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to orderBy **server**.type.id?

Comment: I'm pretty confused about it, it seems that filter:orderBy doesn't need the prefix since it always used in a loop.
EDIT: tested it and yep. It doesn't change anything.
Almost as if the orderBy was ignored for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="server in servers.hits.hits | orderBy:'type.id'">
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bDPW2/1/

More info from the docs:

> filter:orderBy(array, expression[, reverse]);

A string as an expression:

> string: An Angular expression which evaluates to an object to order by, such as 'name' to sort by a property called 'name'. Optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name).

Comment: Well, give us some more information about your server object. As you can see in the fiddle, it's working with the code you provide us.

Comment: My servers come from elasticJS Documents. I don't know what else can be said, it's pretty basic.